How change recording calls layout
I using react sdk and create videochat but have one problem. I recording call and take this calls from storage - and this video recording dont have any styles. So i start searching solution in documentation on getstream.io and find it but only for server side. Solution is add some style in layout option :
client.video.updateCallType(callTypeName, {
  settings: {
    recording: {
      mode: VideoRecordSettingsRequestModeEnum.AVAILABLE,
      audio_only: false,
      quality: VideoRecordSettingsRequestQualityEnum._1080P,
      layout: {
        name: VideoLayoutSettingsNameEnum.SPOTLIGHT,
        options: layoutOptions,
      },
    },
  },
});

but  react sdk client dont have option layout, this client just have mode,audio and quality. in react sdk client create like this
const client = new StreamVideoClient({ apiKey, user, token });

and server side api
client = new StreamClient(apiKey, secret, { timeout: 3000 });

Im using next js and in server side i just create token but client
const client = new StreamVideoClient({ apiKey, user, token });

creating on client side. So i need adding style for layout recording calls
React sdk client dont have option layout, this client just have mode,audio and quality.
